# Unexpected termination of a program in c

Tags: c, struct, printf, scanf

I am beginner in c . Today i faced a problem . As per book if we give following input :

```
Enter names, prices and no. of pages of 3 books 

A  100.00  354 
C  256.50  682 
F  233.70  512
```

the output would come like following

```
And this is what you entered 

A  100.000000  354 
C  256.500000  682 
F  233.700000  512
```

while on running it terminates abruptly .

The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
main( ) 
{ 
    struct book 
    {   
    char  name ; 
    float  price ; 
    int  pages ; 
    } ; 
    struct book  b1, b2, b3 ; 

    printf ( "\nEnter names, prices & no. of pages of 3 books\n" ) ; 
    scanf ( "%c %f %d", &b1.name, &b1.price, &b1.pages ) ; 
    scanf ( "%c %f %d", &b2.name, &b2.price, &b2.pages ) ; 
    scanf ( "%c %f %d", &b3.name, &b3.price, &b3.pages ) ; 

    printf ( "\nAnd this is what you entered" ) ; 
    printf ( "\n%c %f %d", b1.name, b1.price, b1.pages ) ; 
    printf ( "\n%c %f %d", b2.name, b2.price, b2.pages ) ; 
    printf ( "\n%c %f %d", b3.name, b3.price, b3.pages ) ; 
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question is i am not able to give following as an input to my code:A 100.000 354 C 256.5 682 C 233.7 512

Comment: main is supposed to be `int main(void)`, and end with a `return 0;`

Comment: i have tried that as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put spaces before `%c` so if a `\n` is in the buffer it doesn't get read in.

So this should work:

```
scanf(" %c %f %d", &b1.name, &b1.price, &b1.pages);
scanf(" %c %f %d", &b2.name, &b2.price, &b2.pages);
scanf(" %c %f %d", &b3.name, &b3.price, &b3.pages);
     //^ See the space here, if there is no space but still a '\n' in the buffer it get's read
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that scanf() is terribly broken with respect to scanning for strings. In particular, scanf() is NOT able to allocate (via malloc()) a string on the fly and assign it the appropriate substring from the input.

Your code only parses a single character: `%c`

The obvious improvement - to declare something like `char name[40]` in the struct, and then use `%40c` in the scan code - doesn't work either, because it doesn't care about string ends. It will always consume 40 characters from your input, including numbers etc.

That tendency of scanf() to read until it got, what it wants, is also the reason, why your codes ends premature.

So, the usual solution is to read input one line at a time (for example, via fgets() or the rather new library function getline() ) and then use your code to slash that line into appropriate pieces.

Comment: Sorry goal was to enter a character not a string .So why to waste memory ?